# Pandas: extract number from calculation within loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to do calculations within a loop from multiple columns within a pandas dataframe. I want the output to be just a number, but it is in the form [`index` `number` `dtype: int64`]. It seems like it should be easy to get just that number, but I can't figure it out. Here is a simple example of some data and a basic calculation

```
import pandas as pd
# create a little dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1,2],
    'B': [3,4]
})
# create a list to hold results
l1 = []
# run a loop to do a simple example calculation
for i,_ in enumerate(df.A):
    val = df.A[[i]] + df.B[[i]]
    l1.append(val)
```

This is what I get for `l1`:

```
[0    4
 dtype: int64,
 1    6
 dtype: int64]
```

My desired output is

```
[4, 6]
```

I can take the second value from each element in the list, but I want to do something faster, because my dataset is large, and it seems like I should be able to return a calculation without the index and dtype. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you last line within for loop, the original one return `Series` which will cause the 'issue' you mentioned

```
l1 = []
# run a loop to do a simple example calculation
for i,_ in enumerate(df.A):
    val = df.A[[i]] + df.B[[i]]
    l1.append(val.iloc[0])
    
l1
Out[154]: [4, 6]
```